# How do I import configuration classes in a @DataJpaTest in a SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I have a **SpringBoot Application** and I a config package with

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class PersistenceConfig {
}
```

But the **PersistenceConfig** does not get picked up in a **PersonRepositoryTest**

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@DataJpaTest
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    // Tests ...
}
```

However, if I change from `@DataJpaTest to @SpringBootTest`, PersonRepositoryTest will pick up the config.

My **package structure** is

```
- main
    - java
        - config
              PersistenceConfig.java
        - domain
              Person.java
        - persistence
              PersonRepository.java
          Application.java // @SpringBootApplication

- test
    - java
        - persistence
              PersonRepositoryTest.java
```

The [Testing improvements in Spring Boot 1.4](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) suggest to test the persistence layer with @DataJpaTest

**Observation:**
Doing both annotations on the Test class still do not import the config
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest

**Question 1:**
When testing the Persistence Layer with @DataJpaTest
how do I **properly** (best practise way in Spring Boot) import the config package into my Tests?

**Question 2:**
Can it be an acceptable work around using @SpringBootTest? I am aware that @DataJpaTest is also a meta annotation with sensible auto configuration for my database including transaction management. But what If I do not need it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A solution is to use `@Import` to import your configuration to the configuration done by `@DataJpaTest`. This is my understanding of `@Import`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(AuditConfiguration.class)
public class AuditTest {
}
```

with `AuditConfiguration` that enables auditing

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class AuditConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: This solution is superior as it is fine grained and doesn't do the opposite of what the slice expresses.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful and clean solution!!

Answer (score 10):

You can try this: 
annotate `PersistenceConfig`  with `@ComponentScan` to enable component scanning in Spring.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.yourbasepackage")
public class PersistenceConfig {
}
```

With no further configuration, `@ComponentScan` will default to scanning the same package as the `PersistenceConfig` class.

And add the `@Context-Configuration` annotation to tell it to load its configuration from the PersistenceConfig.class.

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes=PersistenceConfig.class)
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    // Tests ...
}
```

Comment: cheers! it works. So when I have more config classes in the config package, all of them will automatically get picked up because I added @ComponentScan to **one** of them in this package?

Comment: Also, why does it work with the SpringBootTest annotation out of the box? There is no ComponentScan annotation anywhere needed.

Comment: I can't tell but i suggeste you to read Spring in action 4th edition chapter 2.2 Automatically wiring beans. You can also read chapter 4 of Spring Boot in Action.

Comment: Okay I will get this book. Thanks George!

Answer (score -1):

After @georges van post I have found out that **ALL configuration classes** get also picked up by just adding one line in the test:

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@DataJpaTest
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.basepackage.config")
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    // Tests ...
}
```

If someone only wants **ONE specific configuration class** you can do:

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyConfig.class)
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    // Tests ...
}
```

Or multiple classes with:

`@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyConfig1.class, MyConfig2.class})`

Comment: You may want to be careful as a `DataJpaTest` is a slice scanning all configurations may introduce unexpected required dependencies if it Enables `@Enablething` with the configuration. This is why you should avoid putting `@Enable` on your application class or rolling them to one big configuration.