# Spring Boot JPA@CreatedDate @LastModifiedDate not being populated when saving the object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am writing an app with Spring Boot + JPA, using a Postgres database. I have a User Entity and I am trying to get a timestamp when the user record is saved and/or modified. This is not working. The record that is being saved has "null" for both createdDate and lastModifiedDate.

Here is all the relevant code in Kotlin:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        val id: UUID? = null,

        @NotNull
        @Column(unique = true)
        val email: String,
        val name: String,
        private val password: String,

        @CreatedDate
        @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        var createdDate: LocalDateTime? = null,

        @LastModifiedDate
        @Column(name = "last_modified_date", nullable = false)
        var lastModifiedDate: LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

My SQL queries to add the date fields look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE app_user
ADD COLUMN last_modified_date TIMESTAMP,
ADD COLUMN created_date TIMESTAMP;
```

I also have a configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
class JpaAuditingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun auditorProvider(): AuditorAware<String> {
        return AuditorAware { Optional.of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.name) }
    }

}
```

And my test class:

```
  @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    val user = User(
            email = "email",
            name = "name",
            password = "password"
    )

    @Test
    fun `it sets the timestamps when a user is created`() {
        userRepository.save(user)
        user.let {
            assertThat(it.createdDate).isNotNull()
            assertThat(it.lastModifiedDate).isNotNull()
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems the problem only happens in tests. It seems to be fine when i execute the same code to create a user in the development environment and not in tests.

Do i need some additional config in the tests?

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried to use the entity manager like this:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var entityManager: TestEntityManager
```

Then in the test do:

```
entityManager.persist(user)
entityManager.flush()
```

And also

```
entityManager.persistAndFlush(user)
```

Still is not populating the timestamps.

Comment: I've edited my question. I am unable to get the date fields auto-populated. Basically my test fails. I end up with a null for the record instead of the timestamps

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The AuditingEntityListener methods are called in the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` phase.

This means they are called just before the insert or update SQL statements are executed.

Read more about JPA events in the Hibernate doc:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks

**Unit Tests**

When using in Tests you have to enable auditing as well on the test

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class EntityListenerTest {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've written an update. I think injecting and using the repository should work for storing the user model exactly as it would outside of the test environment. I also tried to use the TestEntityManager instance to do this. It contains the methods you are describing here.

Comment: I edited my question. You have to explicitly enable auditing in the test

Comment: In case that you are using audit fields like `@CreatedBy` you need also to enable some configuration to configure your @EnableJpaAuditing stuff like AuditorAware. In this case just import additionaly `@Import(YourJPAConfiguration.class)` in test class. Maybe add also `@WithMockUser(username = "testuser")`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705720/how-do-i-import-configuration-classes-in-a-datajpatest-in-a-springboottest (answer from user Sydney)

Comment: For anyone else who landed here but still had issues... it's easy to overlook that the Entity class that uses the `@CreatedDate` annotation (or other auditing annotations) MUST have the `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` annotation at the top of that Entity class. I realize the OP had that in their example code, but I overlooked it.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue (Spring Boot 2.2.1 and JUnit5) with `null` values. Adding `@EnableJpaAuditing` to test class did not work.

My example (did not copy everything):

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Auditable<U> {

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    private U createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime created;
}
```

and respective class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="survey_records")
public class SurveyRecord extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {
```

I had following configuration for auditing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider", dateTimeProviderRef = "auditingDateTimeProvider")
public class JpaAuditingConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "auditingDateTimeProvider")
    public DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider() {
        return () -> Optional.of(OffsetDateTime.now());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
```

To get `@CreatedBy` and `@CreatedDate` working inside test only `@Import` was needed

```
@DataJpaTest
@Import(JpaAuditingConfiguration.class)
class SurveyRecordRepositoryTest {
```

Used references:

- https://springbootdev.com/2018/03/13/spring-data-jpa-auditing-with-createdby-createddate-lastmodifiedby-and-lastmodifieddate/
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10743#issuecomment-416777423

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue, but the reason for my case is that I had `@Transactional` annotation on the test class, after removing that, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

My prefered solution is a set of multiple annotations to ensure test of `@CreatedBy` or `@CreatedDate`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(JPAConfig.class)
@WithMockUser(username = "testuser")
public class MYRepositoryTest {
...
}
```

My Entities looks like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AbstractEntity {

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdOn;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedOn;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;
}
```

My JPA configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class JPAConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return () -> Optional.of(((User)     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername());
    }
}
```

Now your audit fields also created during JPA test:

```
assertThat(result.getCreatedBy()).isNotNull().isEqualTo("testuser");
assertThat(result.getCreatedOn()).isNotNull();
assertThat(result.getUpdatedBy()).isNotNull().isEqualTo("testuser");
assertThat(result.getUpdatedOn()).isNotNull();
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, but other solutions didn't help. (I'm using Kotlin) Then I've realized that I've declared the field with @LastModifiedBy as val, not var, i.e. readonly. It didn't fail to update it, just silently did nothing. When I changed the field declaration to var it started working ok.

Answer (score -3):

you have to use

```
 @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
 
 private LocalDate created = LocalDate.now() ;
```