# Update @LastModifiedDate when update relation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 entities School and Student in my class School I put one `@LastModifiedDate` field, It`s possible to update that field when I change in any relation(Student) add, update or delete

tks

Answer (score 0):

This is related to JPA/Database Auditing. You can refer the below :
[Spring Boot JPA@CreatedDate @LastModifiedDate not being populated when saving the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709727/spring-boot-jpacreateddate-lastmodifieddate-not-being-populated-when-saving-th)