# How can I use @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment) with @DataJpaTest?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, testing, jax-rs

I am trying to test a JAX-RS application but I'd rather not mock the data especially since there's a `buildData` method for an existing `@DataJpaTest`

Here's what I am trying so far:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = MyApp.class
)
@DirtiesContext
@DataJpaTest
public class MyResourceTest {
```

I get the following error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [app.MyResourceTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]

The other ones I saw that are similar do not talk about the `webEnvironment` setting:

- [How do I import configuration classes in a @DataJpaTest in a SpringBootTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705720/how-do-i-import-configuration-classes-in-a-datajpatest-in-a-springboottest)
- [Recommended way to remove @DataJpaTest when used along with @SpringBootTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459713/recommended-way-to-remove-datajpatest-when-used-along-with-springboottest)

There is somewhat of a solution using `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` but when I did that only the first one works because `buildData` is annotated with `@Before` (same as in `@DataJpaTest`) as I want the data to be pristine before each test so I can do failure scenarios.

Switching to `@BeforeClass` also won't work because I won't be able to use the `@Autowire Repository` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when doing the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609911/242042, it solves the immediate problem, but you won't be able to do any tests that involve the database using a REST client as `@Transactional` will prevent the data from being saved for the client to get.

To get this to work, `@Transactional` should not be used.  Instead `DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD` should be used instead.  This dramatically slows down each test (as in 1 second to 10 seconds per test) but at least it works.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = MyApp.class
)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class MyResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) documentation states the following:

> If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but use an embedded database, you should consider `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` rather than this annotation.

---

Keep in mind that [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) is annotated with [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) and [`@DirtiesContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html). So you may need those annotations along with [`@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html).

Comment: Just updating my OP because I did what you had suggested already.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano I've just seen your update. I think `@Transactional` and `@DirtiesContext` should do the trick.

Comment: Update your answer to say `@Transactional` and `@DirtiesContext` so I can accept it.

Comment: Actually there is one issue I found in that when I use restTemplate to get the data it seems there's nothing in the database, but that could be because I did buildData incorrectly.