# How do I use spring @SpringBootTest instead of DataJPATest

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have this code.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = ApiDbApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = "classpath:application.yml")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Transactional
public class LocationIT {

    @MockBean
    CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    @MockBean
    ShipmentRepository shipmentRepository;
    @MockBean
    ContactRepository contactRepository;

    private LocationController locationController;
    private LocationService locationService;

    @Autowired
    LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        locationService = new LocationService(locationRepository);
        this.locationController = new LocationController(locationService);
    }



    @Test
    public void testAddLocation() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        ;
        Location location = Location.builder()
                .id(Long.valueOf(7))
                .city("Fayetteville")
                .lat(32.33)
                .lon(37.49)
                .name("Big place")
                .State("Arkansas").build();

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.restTemplate
                .postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/api/location/save", location, String.class);

        ResponseEntity<List<Location>> results = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:" + port + "/api/location/list",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Location>>(){});


        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, results.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(Collections.singletonList(location), results.getBody());

    }
}
```

Whenever I run the test. My location repository is null and I have the @Repository annotation.
This is the error I get:
No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.apidb.location.LocationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I want to hit the endpoint using restTemplate, so I would rather not use `@DataJPATest`.

This question is similar: [How can I use @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment) with @DataJpaTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609818/how-can-i-use-springboottestwebenvironment-with-datajpatest)

Comment: You can try adding @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { LocationRepository.class}

Comment: johhnyutts  That worked.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you are probably mixing Junit4 and JUnit5 in your unit test which breaks things. I would remove the `@RunWith` and `@ExtendWIth` (the latter is already available on the `@SpringBootTest` annotation). I assume you want to use JUnit5 here and not JUnit4. Also make sure the `@Test` annotation is from the proper package.You should inject the `TestRestTemplate` and remove your `@Before` method (constructing the controller in this test doesn't add anything).

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried removing the EnableJPARepositories.  I changed the test to be jupiter, removed runwith, and extendwith.  I still get the error for repository without the EnableJPARepositories.

Comment: You should also remove the `@TestPropertySource` as you cannot load yml files with it. Please update the question with what you have now. Basically when you  need to put configuration anntations on your test (those `@Enable*` or `@Import`) you are generally doing it wrong. Hence adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` isn't the solution. On a different note I see no use of injecting that repository in your test (as I also mentioned the `@Before` is useless). So you either aren't showing the full test or it really contains things that aren't useful.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's working now.  Thanks!  I think just ran clean a couple times and it worked, so I will make those changes.  The Before is useless.  I was just trying to test something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the test case you are running is the actual one in your post you are doing things wrong

1. You are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5, that won't work in a single class.
2. The `@TestPropertySource` is for property files not yaml files
3. You should autowire the `TestRestTemplate` not create it (this also allows you to remove the `@LocalServerPort` as that is setup already as a base URL.
4. Your `@Before` doesn't really make sense, constructing the service and controller don't add anything in your test, it only takes up memory and execution time.
5. The `ObjectMapper` inside your test method isn't used, so why construct it.
6. The `@SpringBootTest` can figure out the application class itself.
7. The `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` isn't needed, that is only for sliced tests like `@DataJpaTest`, `@DataJdbcTest` etc.

That all being said I would expect something like the following to work

**Assuming** you configured a proper datasource in your `application.yml` in your `src/test/resources`.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        )
class LocationIT {

    @MockBean
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    @MockBean
    private ShipmentRepository shipmentRepository;
    @MockBean
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void testAddLocation() {       
        Location location = Location.builder()
                .id(Long.valueOf(7))
                .city("Fayetteville")
                .lat(32.33)
                .lon(37.49)
                .name("Big place")
                .State("Arkansas").build();

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.restTemplate
                .postForEntity("/api/location/save", location, String.class);

        ResponseEntity<List<Location>> results = restTemplate.exchange("/api/location/list",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Location>>(){});

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, results.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(Collections.singletonList(location), results.getBody());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Johhnyutts answered the question.  The answer was to add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { LocationRepository.class}

Comment: That isn't the solution.